# test for a propertie in JSON project to be empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON object that is passed to one of my functions …

```
{"action":"setProjectAll", "application":{"proId":"new","zoomPosition":35,"scrollerPosition":0,"language":"en","timelinePosition":0}, "clips":[]}
```

How can I test this object for the propertie "clip" to be "[]" (empty)?
Right now in the example above it is empty, however since the object is dynamic I need to test for that property if it contains values or not.

How can that be done?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
if (x.clips && x.clips.length === 0)
```